# Silk Amino Acids and Fruit

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

Can I mix silk amino acids, bamboo extracts and keratin extracts with fresh organic fruits for a hair treatment?

Answer (score 1):

You **probably** can.

So-called silk amino acids are also known as sericin, which are small proteins with a high serine content. There is a review in *Scientific & Industrial Research*, **2004**, *643*, 323-329 ([PDF](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/5393/1/JSIR%2063(4)%20323-329.pdf)) for some background information.

Just like the sericin, keratin extracts are commonly used in hair care products.

Bamboo extracts seem to be used as well, probably due to the flavonoids contained and their antioxidant properties.

All this plus the fruit does not sound harmful in general, however:

- **I can not know whether your skin will show an allergic reaction on one of the ingredients or their combination!**
- You will probably prepare your hair care mixture without any preservatives. It might therefore be a good idea to prepare and use it freshly. You certainly do not want microbial growth in your cosmetics!

*Given that you have beautiful hair while my preferred hair care product is a sharp blade, you might not want to base your experiments on my opinion alone.*